# How to run a command as root?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, su

How can I run a one-shot command as root?
I expect this to work but its clear that I am misusing it.

```
other_user$ sudo su -lc "echo $(whoami)"
# => I expect "root" but get "other_user"
```

Comment: `$(whoami)` is expanded before sudo is run. Put it all in single quotes.

Comment: Wow, I feel really stupid now :D. Thanks, post it as an answer so I can mark it as right!